# Is there a good way to make textures line up to make these fit together seamlessly?

Tags: texturing, shaders

[image]
I'm fairly new with blender and would like to make a smooth face when all the blocks slide together.
File: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1dH9j4AKqkrs3IIdi4fLs41QVwDsAfO5P/view?usp=sharing
Some very non seamless blocks fitting together.

Comment: Hello, it's very hard to understand what you want to do and what's happening, maybe tell a bit more and share your file with its texture?

Comment: Can do! I added the project file. I would like to make the blocks slide into the block and create a seamless cube all together. (The texture is meant to be like a carbon fiber style)